# JVM Java Virtual Machine and stacks

Tags: java, jvm, stack, frame

I have a query which I am interested in, I would like a full explanation though as I cannot find any answers anywhere but can anyone explain to me how the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) uses stacks and stack frames in order to organise its computations?

Comment: Go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html

Comment: It uses the stack frames pretty much the same way as any other language under the Sun. Your question is overly broad and unspecific.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : surely you mean "under the Oracle".

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Ooops... hope I'm not getting sued over that one :)

Answer (score 3):

The Java Bytecode is a so-called [stack-oriented programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language). This model is used by a lot of *virtual machines* - in contrast to the architecture of physical machines.

Here is an example:

```
public static int foobar(int value) {
    return value + 42;
}
```

The Java Bytecode of this method looks as follows:

```
iload_0
bipush 42
iadd
ireturn
```

These instructions do not use *registers*. Instead they use the *stack* for computation:

- Push the first argument onto the stack.
- Push the constant `42` onto the stack.
- Pop two elements from the stack, add them and push the result onto the stack.
- Pop the top element from the stack and return it.

It's the same for all other Java Bytecode operations. There are no *registers* that can be used. All operations push and/or pop elements onto and from the stack.